# Can I declare the some variables in __init__ method in Python other than class attributes?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

Consider the following code:

```
class ElasticMaterial(Material):
    def __init__(self,StressState,e,nu,alpha):
        Material.__init__(self,StressState)
        if self.StressState=='threed':
            lv=6  
        else:
            lv=4
        self.e=e
        self.nu=nu
        self.alpha=alpha
```

Is this valid? If so, how can I call lv in other methods of the same class? If not, how do I modify the code?

Comment: It's completely valid. You're allowed to declare non-attributed variables in the constructor.

Comment: You can define variable lv in this way, but if you are going to call it from other methods, why are you trying NOT to declare it as an attribute variable?

Comment: Is the following valid then?

class ElasticMaterial(Material):
    def __init__(self,StressState,e,nu,alpha):
        Material.__init__(self,StressState)
        if self.StressState=='threed':
            self.lv=6  
        else:
            self.lv=4
        self.e=e
        self.nu=nu
        self.alpha=alpha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to create variables in `__init__` that are accessible to other methods is to define them as attributes on `self`.  I don't know why you want to avoid attributes.